# EMT vs ENT for low-voltage sprinkler solenoid control

Tags: electrical, conduit

I'm putting in a drip irrigation system controlled by 24V Orbit sprinkler valves. The control wire will have to under a deck and across the back of a planter, requiring a water-tight conduit. EMT is slightly cheaper than ENT, so I'm leaning toward EMT for cost reasons. Is there a reason I'm not considering that I should use ENT instead? It will not be in-ground, it will all be above-ground and fastened to a deck or planter.

Comment: For low voltage usually only cost and if it works matters.  Could place it in old garden hose if you wanted.  Code does not worry about low voltage or tell how to do things with it.

Answer (score 4):

Sprinkler control wire, if you buy actual sprinkler control wire, is suitable for direct burial.  It does not need to be in a water tight conduit and is not required by code to be in conduit above or below ground.  IMO you don't need to protect it if it's under a deck and behind a planter.  Try to route the unprotected cable it so that it is neither visible nor prone to damage.

Where it's exposed above ground to damage by people, you can put it in any kind of conduit you want.  If cost is the main factor, I suspect a small diameter PVC drain pipe (plumbing, not electrical) will be the best fit.   If for some reason you want it to be in watertight electrical conduit, use Liquidtight or similar conduit and fittings, not EMT or ENT.

Comment: I'm using riser-rated CAT-5 cable instead of actual sprinkler control wire - I already have the CAT-5 spool from previous projects and I'd rather not spend the money on actual sprinkler control wire if I don't have to.

Comment: 18/7 sprinkler wire is about 50 cents a foot.  If you can find maybe 1/2" PVC drain pipe for less than that ... good luck ... but when you add the fittings and glue I think you'll go back to replacing the cable.  Maybe @crisp659 is onto something ... Go to the dollar store and buy a cheap rubber hose.

Comment: Also the Cat5 will have to come out of your cocoon at least where it's connected to the valves outside and I think you'll be very disappointed by the unreliability of those connections.  Sprinkler wire is #18, ethernet is usually #24.  The valve wires will be designed for waterproof twist nuts.  The ethernet wire will snap if you twist it tightly, it's not meant for that.  So, you gonna add waterproof crimp connectors? $$$.

Comment: Furthermore, "watertight electrical conduit" is NOT dry unless it's connected to a tank venting dry nitrogen (or CO2, etc.) into it. It's **defined as** and also **actually in practice** a *wet location* - which means that your riser Cat5e is going to fail due to being wet in *some unknown but inevitable timeframe.* Condensation alone will make it wet if nothing else does. Wiring in exterior conduits needs to be rater for wet use.

Comment: OK, so it looks like I'm going to end up buying the sprinkler wire after all. Thanks for all the help on this, despite the unexpected direction it took.

Comment: Just another thought, if the entire "irrigation" system is confined to the porch you could put the valves DIRECTLY underneath the controller, so the cable is only a foot long or even less, and run the drip hoses from their pots, under the porch to the combined location of the controller and valves.    You could even put the valves and controller together in the same plastic project box (as long as the controller has a separate AC PSU outside the box) and then you don't need a cable at all, you can just use loose wires to connect the controller to the valves.